# clear text field value in clone object

Tags: jquery, clone

I am having trouble to clear text field value created from jQuery [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.
I am just copying **add_new_content** content and appending that one with last add_new_content element.it works good.But in case, clicking add_new_box after  enter some text in the text fields means. it clones with input value.but i want fresh text field.

Mark up

```
<div class="add_new_content">
<div class="add_new_box">ADD NEW</div>
<input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".add_new_box").live('click',function(){

 $('.add_new_content:last').clone().appendTo('.add_new_content:last');

});

});
```

Working Example is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/KCwYA/)

How can i do that.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can match the cloned `<input>` element with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and reset its value with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
$('.add_new_content:last').clone()
                          .find("input:text").val("").end()
                          .appendTo('.add_new_content:last');
```

Comment: Thanks .end() did the trick for me. But what if I want to clone selectlist (select), how to remove its option?

Comment: Give this man a cookie. Kinjan Bhavsar I think setting the select to val("") should work too.

Answer (score 10):

set the value right before, or after, you clone it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".add_new_box").live('click',function(){

 var clone = $('.add_new_content:last').clone();
 clone.find("input").val("");
 clone.appendTo('.add_new_content:last');

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the value after you clone it eg.

```
var $clone = $('.add_new_content:last').clone();
$clone.find('input').val('');
$clone.appendTo('.add_new_content:last');
```