# delete text content before cloning it with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a form in which users r allowed to duplicate text field.
When a text field is clonated, it contains the words of the original text field.
Id like to delete that text.
Is it possibile?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnCopia").click(function () {

                $("#divToCopy").clone().appendTo("#divToCopyTo");

                // salvo l'html
                $("#textHTML").text($("#divToCopyTo").html());


            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You are not clear in your requirement.What is not working.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845058/clear-text-field-value-in-clone-object This may help you

Comment: Thanks everybody, this is what i was looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845058/clear-text-field-value-in-clone-object.
Thanks shin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#divToCopy").clone().html('').appendTo("#divToCopyTo");
```

It will delete the html inside the div you want to copy.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSk5U/)