# Removing elements from a DIV, and previously inserted values Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was having an issue earlier cloning some HTML within a page I have now resolved the issue using the following JS Fiddle Below:

```
HTML:

<div id='1'>
    <div class="template"> <!-- mark a clone target -->
        ...
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
    </div>
</div>
JS:

var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VcBrz/

EDIT** the first issue I had with cloning and clearing textboxes has been resolved resolved.

If you refer to the JSFiddle above - a new row is added every time a button is clicked on a form. 
I am hoping to add another button to achieve the exact opposite, so rows can be removed on button click, and was wondering whether anyone could suggest an answer?

Comment: Can you clarify this : **How to remove a row after I have added it, and also when new elements are added to the div**

Comment: remove from last or first?

Comment: last added row would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('#add').click(function() { // where add is the id of add button
 $template.clone().insertAfter($template).find("input:text").val("");
});
$('#remove').click(function() { // where remove is the id of remove button
if($('.template').length>1)
 $('.template').last().remove();
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/aa62z/1/)

Comment: ^I have already acheived this functionality - I am finding that when cloning values inserted are remembered when the clone is put on the pafe

Comment: @TotalNewbie well in the fiddle i shared it's not happening. is it..?

Comment: ^it does - fill in a few textboxes click submit and see what happens - It doenst clear them

Comment: @TotalNewbie oops, i didn't check it by entering the values in the clones itself... check the update, if something is missing comment below. ~

Comment: Thanks very much even acheived the remove functionality thanks very much much!

Answer (score 1):

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aa62z/)

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template).find("input:text").val("");
});
```

## Reference : [clear text field value in clone object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845058/clear-text-field-value-in-clone-object)

---

## Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdLep/)

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[name=addNewRow]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template).find("input:text").val("");
});
$('input[name=removeRow]').click(function() {
    $('.template').filter(":not(:first-child)").get(-1).outerHTML = "";
});
```

Comment: thankyou exactly what I was looking for - have you got any idea how I could remove a row from the page?

Comment: Can you calrify more.Do u want only one row on insert. i.e. remove previous row?

Comment: ^ I haved edited the question ^ yes I would now like to a button to clear a singular row.

Comment: @TotalNewbie i was busy so I wasnt able to reply with an update.I am just posting an update now .Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks very much - absolutely perfect for what I was looking for thankyou!

Comment: @TotalNewbie alwys glad to help